# What does the red exclamation mark in my layout file mean?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

Android Studio is showing me a red exclamation mark next to a attribute, but the code works fine.

[image: red exclamation mark]

What does it mean?

Comment: Mouse over for tooltips.

Comment: No tooltips on mouse over, no explanation at all, that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry,it's not an error from the code. It tells "Android Studio failed to display thumbnail of the given drawable.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! A bit confusing, looks like an error.

Comment: was my answer useful to you?

Comment: @Androider, how to turn it off?

Comment: @andranikAzizbekyan, try to Clean Your Project & Rebuild by:-

Build > Clean Project Then Build > Rebuild Project

Then Click Invalidate Caches/Restart Options